# How to use python os.walk, but first get the subfolders and then the files as XML file

Tags: python, xml

I'm python beginner and started to work on the below script. It already works, but in the wrong way. Now i get stuck and I would like some help. I use os.walk in order to get an index as a XML file of a filepath in Windows. I also added the current result of the script, and what I need to get out.

The difference between the result and what i need, is that the subfolders are before the files.

```
##This Script creates an Index as XML file of a filepath in Windows
import os

#variable
CrawlingStartpoint = r"D:\DATA\WorldDem"
XMLfile = r"xml_index.xml"
XMLLocation = r"D:\DATA\\"
XMLFileLocation = XMLLocation + XMLfile
text = ""

#Standard Starting text for the XML file
text += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<ShoeBox>\n<Version>2011</Version>\n<FileGroup>\n<Title>ShoeBox: "
text += XMLfile + "</Title>\n<Description>" + CrawlingStartpoint + "</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"

#Scan all folders, subfolders and files. It writes foldernames, subfolder names and files.
#It write a closegroup for every subfolder  to build the filestructure in a XML file.
startdept = CrawlingStartpoint.split('\\')
startdept = len(startdept) - 1
old = startdept - 1
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(CrawlingStartpoint, topdown=True):
    path = root.split('\\')
    if (len(path) - 1) < old:
            text += (((old - (len(path) - 1))+1)*'</FileGroup>\n')
            old = (len(path) -1)
    elif (len(path) - 1) == old:
        text += "</FileGroup>\n"
    if os.path.join(root) <> CrawlingStartpoint:
        text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + os.path.basename(root) + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".img") or filename.endswith(".jp2") or filename.endswith(".tif"):
            text += "<File>\n<Path>" + os.path.join(root, filename) + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
        elif filename.endswith(".shp") or filename.endswith(".dxf"):
            text += "<File>\n<Path>" + os.path.join(root, filename) + "</Path>\n<Type>vector</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
    if (len(path) - 1) > old:
        old = old + 1
text += (((len(path) -1) - startdept)*'</FileGroup>\n')

#Standard Closing text for the XML file
text += "</FileGroup>" + "\n" + "</ShoeBox>"

#Write the filelocations stored in text in the textfile
myfile = open(XMLFileLocation,'a')
myfile.write(text)
myfile.close()
```

### Result of my script :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ShoeBox>
                <Version>2011</Version>
                <FileGroup>
                               <Title>ShoeBox: xml_index.xml</Title>
                               <Description>D:\DATA\WorldDem</Description>
                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                               <FileGroup>
                                               <Title>srtm_geotiff_download</Title>
                                               <Description>noop</Description>
                                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                                                               <File>
                                                               <Path>D:\DATA\WorldDem\srtm_geotiff_download\srtm1_90m_v41.img</Path>
                                                               <Type>raster</Type>
                                                               <Description></Description>
                                                               </File>
                               </FileGroup>
                               <FileGroup>
                                               <Title>viewfinderpanoramas</Title>
                                               <Description>noop</Description>
                                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                                               <File>
                                                               <Path>D:\DATA\WorldDem\viewfinderpanoramas\mosaic_vfp_90m_bewerkt_20140211.img</Path>
                                                               <Type>raster</Type>
                                                               <Description></Description>
                                               </File>
                                               <FileGroup>
                                                               <Title>Compressed</Title>
                                                               <Description>noop</Description>
                                                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                                                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                                               </FileGroup>
                                               <FileGroup>
                                                               <Title>Modellen</Title>
                                                               <Description>noop</Description>
                                                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                                                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                                               </FileGroup>
                               </FileGroup>
                </FileGroup>
</ShoeBox>
```

### Result needed :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ShoeBox>
                <Version>2011</Version>
                <FileGroup>
                               <Title>ShoeBox: xml_index.xml</Title>
                               <Description>D:\DATA\WorldDem</Description>
                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                               <FileGroup>
                                               <Title>srtm_geotiff_download</Title>
                                               <Description>noop</Description>
                                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                                                               <File>
                                                               <Path>D:\DATA\WorldDem\srtm_geotiff_download\srtm1_90m_v41.img</Path>
                                                               <Type>raster</Type>
                                                               <Description></Description>
                                                               </File>
                               </FileGroup>
                               <FileGroup>
                                               <Title>viewfinderpanoramas</Title>
                                               <Description>noop</Description>
                                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                                               <FileGroup>
                                                               <Title>Compressed</Title>
                                                               <Description>noop</Description>
                                                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                                                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                                               </FileGroup>
                                               <FileGroup>
                                                               <Title>Modellen</Title>
                                                               <Description>noop</Description>
                                                               <Expanded>false</Expanded>
                                                               <AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>
                                               </FileGroup>
                                               <File>
                                                               <Path>D:\DATA\WorldDem\viewfinderpanoramas\mosaic_vfp_90m_bewerkt_20140211.img</Path>
                                                               <Type>raster</Type>
                                                               <Description></Description>
                                               </File>
                               </FileGroup>
                </FileGroup>
</ShoeBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any easy way to do what you want. At least, there isn't if you're writing your XML by hand.

The reason is that you need to build your XML document from the root up, starting with the outermost directory, producing the top-most `<FileGroup>` tag. On the other hand, you want to dive into the subfolders before you write out the files from each folder, so that files in the leaf directories will appear first, and those in the root directory will be last. Those two goals are in tension with each other.

I think there are two strategies that you could take to solving the problem.

The first is to use a more sophisticated approach to writing your XML file. For instance, if you use a library that lets you dynamically create the elements of the document, rather than just using string manipulations, you may be able to insert the subfolder information above the file information, even though you're process them in the same order you do now (files first). I don't know Python's XML libaries very well, so I don't have any specific suggestions here, but probably the place to start is the documentation on the [`xml`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) package in the standard library (you'll probably just want a submodule like `xml.etree.Etree`, but I'm not sure if that's the best one for your task, so check the package out and read up on whichever parts look appropriate).

The other option would be to change up how you get your data. If you dropped the `topdown=True` argument to `os.walk`, it would start with some deeper folders first, then come back to the higher level ones, which is exactly the order you want to be showing their files. The tricky part about this is that you'd need to build the higher level `<FileGroup>` tags before you get around to processing the folders they are for. You'll need to deduce the depth you're at based on the paths of the folders, but you're already doing some of this, so it probably won't be too much more complicated. (By the way, you really should be using the functions in the `os.path` module for file path manipulations, rather than doing things like `my_path.split("\\")`.)

Answer (score 0):

After the comments of Blcknght, I removed the "\\" and os specific stuff. **The script works now on windows and linux, and the results are good.** I completely started over, on the main script. I didn't use the xml package, but therefor I created 2 functions, which uses os.listdir() instead of os.walk. Below you find the script.

If you read the script you noticed on the main part there are al lot of "for" loops and "if" statements. Per subfolder the script does the same over-over again. But I can't figure it out, how to put this a "for" loop.

I could find out how much subfolders are within the given search folder. But I need some help how to create a loop for the main script. I could use some help here :)

```
##This Script creates an Index as XML file of a filepath
import os

#variable
CrawlingStartpoint = "D:\DATA\WorldDEM"
XMLfile = r"python.xml"
XMLLocation = r"D:\DATA"
XMLFileLocation = XMLLocation + os.path.sep + XMLfile
text = ""

#Standard Starting text for the XML file
text += "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<ShoeBox>\n<Version>2011</Version>\n<FileGroup>\n<Title>XMLBox: "
text += XMLfile + "</Title>\n<Description>" + CrawlingStartpoint + "</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"

#function with a directory as input, give back all subdirectories in a list
def getdirs(startingdir):
    folderlist = list()
    folders = os.listdir(startingdir)
    for folder in folders:
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(startingdir, folder)) == True:
                folderlist.append(os.path.join(startingdir, folder))
    return folderlist

#function with a directory as input, give back all files that ends with img,jp2,tif,shp and dxf in a list
def getfiles(startingdir):
    filelist = list()
    bestanden = os.listdir(startingdir)
    for bestand in bestanden:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(startingdir, bestand)) == True:
            if bestand.endswith(".img") or bestand.endswith(".jp2") or bestand.endswith(".tif"):
                filelist.append(os.path.join(startingdir, bestand))
    return filelist

#Scans all files and subfolders. Scans up to the 13th subfolder.
text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + CrawlingStartpoint + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
if getdirs(CrawlingStartpoint):
    for dir0 in getdirs(CrawlingStartpoint):
        text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir0 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
        if getdirs(dir0):
            for dir1 in getdirs(dir0):
                text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir1 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                if getdirs(dir1):
                    for dir2 in getdirs(dir1):
                        text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir2 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                        if getdirs(dir2):
                            for dir3 in getdirs(dir2):
                                text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir3 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                if getdirs(dir3):
                                    for dir4 in getdirs(dir3):
                                        text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir4 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                        if getdirs(dir4):
                                            for dir5 in getdirs(dir4):
                                                text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir5 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                                if getdirs(dir5):
                                                    for dir6 in getdirs(dir5):
                                                        text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir6 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                                        if getdirs(dir6):
                                                            for dir7 in getdirs(dir6):
                                                                text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir7 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                                                if getdirs(dir7):
                                                                    for dir8 in getdirs(dir7):
                                                                        text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir8 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                                                        if getdirs(dir8):
                                                                            for dir9 in getdirs(dir8):
                                                                                text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir9 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                                                                if getdirs(dir9):
                                                                                    for dir10 in getdirs(dir9):
                                                                                        text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir10 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                                                                        if getdirs(dir10):
                                                                                            for dir11 in getdirs(dir10):
                                                                                                text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir11 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                                                                                if getdirs(dir11):
                                                                                                    for dir12 in getdirs(dir11):
                                                                                                        text += "<FileGroup>\n<Title>" + dir12 + "</Title>\n<Description>noop</Description>\n<Expanded>false</Expanded>\n<AddOutputs>false</AddOutputs>\n"
                                                                                                        if getdirs(dir12):
                                                                                                            for dir13 in getdirs(dir12):
                                                                                                                text += "--Error to much subfolders--" + dir13 + "\n"
                                                                                                                if getdirs(dir13):
                                                                                                                    for dir14 in getdirs(dir13):
                                                                                                                        text += "--Error to much subfolders--" + dir14 + "\n"
                                                                                                                if getfiles(dir13):
                                                                                                                    for files13 in getfiles(dir13):
                                                                                                                        text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files13 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                                                                                                text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                                                                                        if getfiles(dir12):
                                                                                                            for files12 in getfiles(dir12):
                                                                                                                text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files12 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                                                                                        text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                                                                                if getfiles(dir11):
                                                                                                    for files11 in getfiles(dir11):
                                                                                                        text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files11 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                                                                                text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                                                                        if getfiles(dir10):
                                                                                            for files10 in getfiles(dir10):
                                                                                                text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files10 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                                                                        text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                                                                if getfiles(dir9):
                                                                                    for files9 in getfiles(dir9):
                                                                                        text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files9 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                                                                text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                                                        if getfiles(dir8):
                                                                            for files8 in getfiles(dir8):
                                                                                text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files8 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                                                        text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                                                if getfiles(dir7):
                                                                    for files7 in getfiles(dir7):
                                                                        text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files7 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                                                text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                                        if getfiles(dir6):
                                                            for files6 in getfiles(dir6):
                                                                text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files6 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                                        text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                                if getfiles(dir5):
                                                    for files5 in getfiles(dir5):
                                                        text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files5 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                                text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                        if getfiles(dir4):
                                            for files4 in getfiles(dir4):
                                                text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files4 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                        text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                                if getfiles(dir3):
                                    for files3 in getfiles(dir3):
                                        text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files3 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                                text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                        if getfiles(dir2):
                            for files2 in getfiles(dir2):
                                text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files2 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                        text += "</FileGroup>\n"
                if getfiles(dir1):
                    for files1 in getfiles(dir1):
                        text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files1 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
                text += "</FileGroup>\n"
        if getfiles(dir0):
            for files0 in getfiles(dir0):
                text += "<File>\n<Path>" + files0 + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
        text += "</FileGroup>\n"
if getfiles(CrawlingStartpoint):
    for filesCrawlingStartpoint in getfiles(CrawlingStartpoint):
        text += "<File>\n<Path>" + filesCrawlingStartpoint + "</Path>\n<Type>raster</Type>\n<Description></Description>\n</File>\n"
text += "</FileGroup>\n"


#Standard Closing text for the XML file
text += "</FileGroup>\n</XMLBox>"
print text

#Write the filelocations stored in text in the textfile
myfile = open(XMLFileLocation,'a')
myfile.write(text)
myfile.close()
```